# pow(x,y) works with floating point numbers but not with integers

Tags: c, floating-point, integer

I wrote a program that calculates the cubes of the first five numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
  for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    printf("%d ",pow(i,3));
  }
}
```

This does not work. It prints:

```
0 0 0 0 0
```

However, using float it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
  printf("%f\n",pow(3,3));
  for(float i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    printf("%f ",pow(i,3));
  }
}
```

And prints:

```
1.000000 8.000000 27.000000 64.000000 125.000000
```

What is the problem with integers? Why does this only work with floating point numbers?

Comment: Did you check the documented return value type of pow? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow Using the wrong format specifier in printf causes undefined behavior. Knowing that, what is your question?

Comment: Your issue doesn't have anything to do with `pow`

Comment: @user3483203 Please elaborate. I do see a relevance of  `pow()` and its specification.

Comment: Was responding to the question, not your comment, sorry if that was unclear.  The issue is because of the `printf`. It doesn't really have anything to do with `pow`, since he is giving it the same inputs in both cases.

Comment: The syntax for `pow()` is `double pow(double x, double y);`   Notice that nothing in the parameters nor the returned value is `int`.  And when passing it `float` parameters, they are automatically promoted to `double`.  Strongly suggest reading/understanding the MAN pages for those C library functions you are using.

Comment: if you really want to use `float`, then you 'should' use: `float powf(float x, float y);`

Comment: Your question isn't a question at all--merely a correct observation. If your real question is "why", the simplest answer is that integer exponentiation doesn't come up that often in real life, so they didn't bother putting it into the library. It's easy to find code to do this, but make sure you find code that uses the correct shift-and-square method rather than naive repeated multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all pow(i,j) returns double value, not an integer. Try this code

```
int main() {
     for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
         printf("%f ",pow(i,3));
     }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is, *why* float should be used, *not* what should be used.

Comment: Or you can use `printf("%d ",(int)pow(i,3));` but don't be surprised if it sometimes prints a value that you don't expect.

Comment: @MysteriousUser go through this link http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/math.h.html  . The pow() supports only double and float returns only.

Comment: @MysteriousUser Since `pow` returns float, that's the type you *must* use in the `printf` format statement.  `printf` is special (or, you might say, deficient): it has no way of noticing that you passed a `double`, but `%d` expects an int.